# Booking.com didn’t call hotel to cancel should I be worried?

Tags: hotels

I canceled  7 hotels through the refund period and found at least two that were not contacted. I called customer service and they were able to get me my two refunds as well as call a third hotel. I am worried about getting charged for the other hotels and am concerned about using booking.com in the future. What rights do I have? I have all cancelation emails

Comment: Hotels do not have your credit card information, so they cannot charge you. Possibly they do not have your name, until really last days (so booking can change person, using some "special deals"). Note some rooms are reserved for booking.com.

Answer (score 5):

When you have the cancelation confirmation of booking.com you have cancelled.
Whether you still have to pay depends on the cancelation rules for this booking, but the date of you confirmation mail or message is the one that counts, not when the hotel hears about it.